# Problem 4.2 Gilbarg/Trudinger

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Problem 4.2 **Prove lemma (4.2) if $f$ is Dini continuous in $\Omega.$**

> **Lemma:** Let $f$ bounded and locally Hölder continuous (with exponent $\alpha \le 1)$ in $\Omega,$ and let $w$ be the Newtonian potential of $f.$ Then $w \in C^2(\Omega), \Delta w = f$ in $\Omega,$ and for any $x \in \Omega$
>   \begin{equation}
> D_{ij}w(x) = \int_{\Omega_0} D_{ij}\Gamma(x-y)(f(y) - f(x))dy -f(x)\int_{\partial \Omega_0} D_i \Gamma(x-y) \nu_j(y) dS
> \end{equation}
>   here $\Omega_0$ is any domain contained $\Omega$ for which the divergence theorem holds and $f$ is extended to vanish outside $\Omega.$

This is in lemma 4.2 Hölder continuity can be replaced by Dini continuiuty.

My intention here is that I have saw that this can help to obtain the following

> *If $f \in C^{Dini}(B_1)$ then $f$ is a function such that there is $v \in C^{1,1}(B_1)$ with $f= \Delta v$ in the weak sense.*

This is in fact my main goal. Any help or reference will be very grateful.

> **Definition:** We say that $f$ is Dini continuous or $f \in C^{Dini}(B_1)$ if there exist a modulus of continuity $\sigma$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_o^{1/2} \dfrac{\sigma(r)}{r} dr < \infty.
> \end{equation}

Comment: What is your difficulty in modifying the given proof?